# Installing Magick++ in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, image-processing, visual-studio-code, imagemagick

I have tried to install Magick++.h in visual studio 2019. 
First I download ImageMagick++ and installed my pc. Then I copied include & library path to project properties. there is no error when I am writing the program. after compiling, there is a build error. Can someone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the build error ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with detailed steps on how to reproduce your build error. And also include the excat build error.

Comment: Under Windows it may be necessary to initialize the ImageMagick library prior to using the Magick++ library. This initialization is performed by passing the path to the ImageMagick DLLs (assumed to be in the same directory as your program) to the InitializeMagick() function call.